# Vue - passing params to route as props is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am passing params to a named route from a component:

```
      <v-list-tile
        :key="team.logo_url"
        :to="{name: 'team', params: {
          id: team.id,
          name: team.name
        }}"
        avatar
      >
```

The route is sett up likes so:

```
{
  path: "/team",
  name: "team",
  component: TeamInfo,
  props: {
    id: true,
    name: true
  }
}
```

But the component does not render the props when referenced:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
      <p>{{ id }}</p>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>

  import TeamService from '@/services/TeamService';

  export default {
    props: ['id', 'name'],
    data: () => ({
        players: [],
        games: []
    }),
    mounted() {
        console.log(this.id);
    }
  }
</script>
```

The log in the mounted method returns `undefined`.

However when I look in Vue dev-tools at the `TeamInfo` component I can see that both props are undefined but the params are populated.

I would like to be able to use the props in the component and also populate the URL with the team ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `boolean` mode for to pass the params to both the URL and props. You also have to define the parameter inside the `path` to be able to access it. Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/o41j762pnz) that shows how to use it.

```
{
  name: "team",
  path: "/team/:id",
  component: TeamInfo,
  props: true,
}
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Comment: Tried this and it does not solve the issue.  I still get undefined when trying to log the props.  I am not so concerned with the URL for now as it is more worrying that I cannot get the params as props into the TeamInfo component.

Comment: You also have to define the parameter inside the `path` with `/team/:id` otherwise the prop is not taken into account. I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Yes I did this. Path is fine now.

Comment: Can't get the props into the component from the route however.

Comment: Did you checked the example I've linked in the answer?

Comment: This solution works, but still I have a problem - I was already using props to pass an extra hard-coded parameter (in addition to that `id` parameter) like this:
`props: {foo: 'bar'}`. Does someone know how to pass both things?
Does someone know how to deal with that?

Comment: I figured my question out:
`{
  name: "team",
  path: "/team/:id",
  component: TeamInfo,
  props: route => {
      return {
        id: route.params.id,
        foo: "bar"
      }
    }
}`