# Cannot pass an object to a new route using props

Tags: vuejs2

I am working on a project where a user fills in a quiz and the results need to be passed to a new page. The quiz has the Quiz component, where the quiz is taken, and the QuizFinished component, where the user can go to the Results page. I have been able to pass the quiz answers to QuizFinished, but the problem lies in passing the answers from QuizFinished to QuizResults. I have copied some code from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/o41j762pnz) which is from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077673/vue-passing-params-to-route-as-props-is-undefined) stackoverflow question, but the code does not work.
Am I missing something here?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Quiz.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="quiz-background py-5" id="mood-finder">
    <b-container class="text-center">
      <h1 class="">Mood finder</h1>
      <component
 <!-- This event is triggered when a question is answered in Question.vue, that works -->
        v-on:click="_answerQuestion($event)"
<!-- Going from the startpage to the quiz -->
        v-on:start="this.startQuiz"
        v-bind:is="component"
<!-- Binds the answers to be read in QuizResult -->
        :answers="answers"
        ref="question"
      />
      <b-row class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <b-col cols="12" md="8" class="pt-3">
<!-- A progress bar -->
          <b-progress
            variant="primary"
            aria-label="Voortgang van de Moodfinder"
            :value="progress"
            :max="maxProgress"
          ></b-progress>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import quizStart from "./QuizStart.vue";
import question from "./Question";
import strawberry from "../assets/strawberry.webp";
import banana from "../assets/banana.webp";
import quizFinished from "./QuizFinished.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    quizStart,
    question,
    quizFinished,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      questionIndex: 0,
<!--The array with the answers. It is put in an object to circumvent the array limitation by Vue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1798 -->
      answers: {array: []},
      component: "quizStart",
      strawberry: strawberry,
      banana: banana,
      progress: 0,
      maxProgress: 99,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * @description
     * saved pressed answer text in answers array
     */
    _answerQuestion(chosenItem) {
      this.answers.array.push(chosenItem);
      this.switchQuestion();
    },
    startQuiz(){
      this.component= "question"
    },
    /**
     * @description switches the questions when the user performs an action in the quiz
     * it swaps out the quiz images, text and quiz question for each question.
     */
    switchQuestion() {
      /**
       * questionIndex stands for the question the user would like to go to.
       * So e.g questionIndex = 1 is going to the second question (counting from 0)
       */
      this.questionIndex++;
      switch (this.questionIndex) {
        case 0:
          this.progress = 0;
        break;
        // //For question 1, see Question.Vue data field
        case 1:
          this.$refs.question.setQuestion("Question 2");
          this.$refs.question.setItems(
            { name: "strawberry", variety: "sweet" },
            { name: "strawberry", variety: "sweet" },
            { name: "strawberry", variety: "sweet" },
            { name: "strawberry", variety: "sweet" }
          );
          this.$refs.question.setImage(
            this.strawberry,
            this.strawberry,
            this.strawberry,
            this.strawberry
          );
          this.progress = 33;
          break;
        case 2:
          console.log(this.questionIndex)
          this.$refs.question.setQuestion("Question 3");
          this.$refs.question.setItems(
            { name: "banana", variety: "sweet" },
            { name: "banana", variety: "sweet" },
            { name: "banana", variety: "sweet" },
            { name: "banana", variety: "sweet" }
          );
          this.$refs.question.setImage(
            this.banana,
            this.banana,
            this.banana,
            this.banana
          );
          this.progress = 66;
          break;
        case 3:
          this.progress = 99;
       //Goes to the quizFinished component
          this.component = quizFinished;
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

//removed the styles
```

QuizFinished.vue:

```js
<template>
  <b-row class="d-flex justify-content-center py-3">
    <b-col class="col-6 col-lg-2">
      <p class="text-white">
        De Mood finder is gemaakt. Je resultaten staan klaar!
      </p>
      <!-- <router-link :to="{ path: '/results/', params: { answers: answers } }"
        ><button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
          Verder naar resultaten
        </button></router-link
      > -->
      <br />
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'results', params: { params: answers} }"
        >Go to results</router-link>
<!-- For testing purposes, the answers are shown here as: { "array": [{object1} etc.]} -->
      {{ answers }}
    </b-col>
  </b-row>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "quizFinished",
  props: {
//For reasoning behind type: Object, see previous codeblock
    answers: { type: Object, required: false },
  },
};
</script>

//removed styles
```

QuizResult.vue

```js
<!-- Html here -->

<script>
export default {
   props: {
    params: { type: Object, required: false },
  },
  mounted() {
//returns undefined, adding a html object like this: {{params}} returns nothing
    console.log(this.params);
  }
};
</script>

//removed styles
```

main.js:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import './registerServiceWorker';
import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';
import '../src/scss/bootstrap.css';
// Import for fontAwesome : svg-core, brand icons and vue
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta';

library.add(fab);
// fontawesome component neccesary to call
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon, fab);
// Make BootstrapVue available throughout your project
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon, fab);
Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
Vue.use(IconsPlugin);
Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueMeta);

import results from './components/pages/Results';
import index from './components/pages/Index';
import pageNotFound from './components/pages/PageNotFound';
import webshop from './components/pages/Webshop';

const resultsRoute = { path: '/results', name: 'results', component: results, props: true, };
const indexRoute = { path: '/', name: 'index', component: index };
const pageNotFoundRoute = { path: '*', name: 'pageNotFound', component: pageNotFound };
const webshopRoute = { path: '/webshop', name: 'webshop', component: webshop };

const routes = [resultsRoute, indexRoute, pageNotFoundRoute, webshopRoute];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history',
});

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    router,
    render: function(h) {
        return h(App);
    },
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is pushing to the router directly like this:

In the button:

```
v-on:click="toResults()"
```

And in methods:

```
         toResults() {
          this.$router.push({
            name: "resultsRoute",
            params: {
              items: this.answers,
            }
```

I was then able to get the items on the other side like this:

```
vm.$route.params.items
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very quick snippet to show quiz using VueRouter:

```js
const QuizStart = {
  template: `
    <div><router-link :to="'/question/0'">START</router-link></div>
  `
}

const QuizQuestion = {
  props: ['qidx', 'questions'],
  computed: {
    question() {
      return this.questions[this.qidx]
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setAnswer(val) {
      this.$emit('set-answer', {
        id: this.qidx,
        answer: val
      })
      let next = ''
      if (Number(this.qidx) < this.questions.length - 1) {
        next = `/question/${ Number(this.qidx) + 1 }`
      } else {
        next = '/result'
      }
      this.$router.push(next)
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ question.text }}:<br />
      <button @click="() => setAnswer(1)">YES</button> | <button @click="() => setAnswer(-1)">NO</button>
    </div>
  `
}

const QuizResult = {
  props: ['questions'],
  computed: {
    computedResult() {
      return this.questions.reduce((a, c) => a + c.answer, 0)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Your score is {{ computedResult }}
    </div>
  `
}

const routes = [{
    path: '/',
    component: QuizStart
  },
  {
    path: '/question/:qidx',
    component: QuizQuestion,
    props: true
  },
  {
    path: '/result',
    component: QuizResult
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes // short for `routes: routes`
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    QuizStart,
    QuizQuestion,
    QuizResult,
  },
  router,
  data() {
    return {
      questions: [{
          text: 'Is this the first question?',
          answer: null,
        },
        {
          text: 'Is this the second question?',
          answer: null,
        },
        {
          text: 'Is this the third question?',
          answer: null,
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setAnswer({
      id,
      answer
    }) {
      this.questions[id].answer = answer
    },
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        QUESTIONS STATE: {{ questions }}
      </div>
      <hr />
      <router-view
        :questions="questions"
        @set-answer="(data) => setAnswer(data)"
      ></router-view>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can see that

- the whole quiz state is tracked in one place: the question components do nothing but display the question and emit the answer back to the parent to update the state;
- the questions are passed down from the parent; the `route` param (`:qidx`) is used to choose which question to display;
- when the last question is reached, the next step is automatically the result page; but, because ALL the pages in the `router-view` receive the state of the questions, it's easy to calculate a result based on any calculation rule you might need.

I hope this helps you in a "smooth quiz-flow" :)

Comment: I see how your code can help, but I am having problems loading it as a part of my index page. This quiz is namely a component on the home page and this code is a whole new router view. Could you point me to some documentation that might help with that?

Comment: @Stijn sorry, but I cannot be sure what to add as a next step that might work with your setup. It could be `children routes`, `named routes`, etc. Or it could be easier to just do it without routing or with a pre-made quiz component/solution.